# flex 4 load module

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, module, load

Can anybody give me an example how to load the module? For example if I have module `Login.mxml` in Modules.user package, how to load it? I want both mxml and actionscript methods.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: i looked up in the internet but i didn't find anything. I found information how to load swf file as module but not mxml file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you read the docs on [loading and unloading Modules](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf64277-7ffd.html)?

To quote some code, this is how you'd load it in MXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- modules/MySimplestModuleLoader.mxml -->
<s:Application 
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <s:ModuleLoader url="ColumnChartModule.swf"/>

</s:Application>
```

[End doc quoting here]

In ActionScript, you'd create an instance of the ModuleLoader class and add it as a child to the parent container, conceptually like this:

```
var myLoader : ModuleLoader = new ModuleLoader();
myLoader.url = "ColumnChartModule.swf";
this.addChild(myLoader);
```

Comment: ok but i have module Login.mxml not login.swf.

Comment: @Volter Without seeing your code; it's tough to give a specific answer.  When you say "Module" are you using the term generically to mean component?  Or did you actually extend the Module class? http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/modules/Module.html .  If so, you have to compile your module to a SWF before you can use it as a Module..

Comment: i have compiled my mxml module into swf but the code doesn't works. import spark.modules.ModuleLoader
   
   private function test():void{
    var myLoader : ModuleLoader = new ModuleLoader();
    myLoader.url = "Modules\User\Login.swf";
    this.addChild(myLoader);
   }

Comment: Please quantify doesn't work.  Do you get compile time errors or run time errors?

Comment: @Volter Perhaps you should consider posting a new question which explains what you're doing and what is going wrong.  Be sure to include any relevant code and the actual runtime errors you're receiving.